# Opendaylight and snmp4sdn plugin work or not

Tags: snmp, sdn, opendaylight, openflow

I'm testing SDN controller ODL and looking onto snmp support where there is a plugin of snmp4sdn under ODL project.

I follow the guideline ..create switch list db file in csv and vendor specific file in xml. I able to read and print the db

```
opendaylight-user@root>snmp4sdn:printdb
MAC_address (sid)                               IP_address      
SNMP_community  CLI_username    CLI_password    Model_name
=======================================================================
00:00:90:94:e4:23:13:e0 (158969157063648     )  192.168.0.32    private         
admin           password        D-Link_DGS3650
00:00:90:94:e4:23:0b:00 (158969157061376     )  192.168.0.33    private         
admin           password        D-Link_DGS3650
00:00:90:94:e4:23:0b:20 (158969157061408     )  192.168.0.34    private         
admin           password        D-Link_DGS3650
```

This is my install snmp4sdn

```
opendaylight-user@root>bundle:list | grep snmp4sdn
295 | Active   |  80 | 0.3.4.Beryllium-SR4                | 
org.opendaylight.snmp4sdn.md-model
296 | Active   |  80 | 0.3.4.Beryllium-SR4                | snmp4sdn plugin
```

But when i do curl of topodiscover or topodiscoverswitch...i got empty

```
opendaylight-user@root>snmp4sdn:topodiscover
opendaylight-user@root>snmp4sdn:topodiscoverswitches
opendaylight-user@root>

rpc get-node-list is called, node list:
```

I have tested with Beryllium and Carbon... both same issue.

May I know if anyone have successfully done it? I have follow the instruction and facing some issues such as no topology/devices discover via curl even do i able to print all the devices list (sample csv) on the terminal. The documentation does not help much on how I can do the troubleshooting. If anyone have successfully dun odl with snmp4sdn please advise me further... I have do it for few days without any good progress.. Appreciate someone to clarify and help. Thank you.

```
https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/SNMP4SDN:User_Guide
```

Comment: I hope someone who familiar with ODL able to help me on this matter. Please advise further. Thanks

Comment: I don't think anyone on this forum would be familiar with the snmp4sdn project. I'd suggest posting to the project's mailing list: snmp4sdn-dev@lists.opendaylight.org.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will do that...thanks again...